# Разбить массив на двумерный массив, таким образом, чтобы длина в пикселях каждого уже разбитого элемента была меньше либо равна определенному значению

Tags: python-3.x, массивы, алгоритм, циклы

Мне нужно разбить исходный массив на двумерный массив, таким образом: каждый элемент исходного массива разбить на отдельные элементы, чтобы длина каждого уже разбитого элемента в пикселях была меньше либо равна определенному максимому. К примеру, мы имеем массив

```py
['Разнообразный и богатый опыт консультация', 'с широким активом требуют определения и уточнения форм развития. Повседневная практика']
```

после преобразований он должен преобрести вид

```py
[['Разнообразный и богатый', 'опыт консультация'], ['с широким активом требуют', 'определения и уточнения форм', 'развития. Повседневная практика']]
```

Для рассчета длины строки в пикселях я использовал библиотеку *PIL.ImageFont*, которая на выходе дает кортеж с высотой и длинной строки в пикселях.

По итогу у меня получилось вот такая функция:

```py
import logging
from PIL import ImageFont

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
font = ImageFont.truetype("OpenSans.ttf", 14)
max_length = 306

def split_list(source):
    # 'source' must be only list!
    result = []

    logging.info("Start to splitting list")
    for index in range(len(source)):
        # font.getsize returns (x, y)
        if font.getsize(source[index])[0] <= max_length:
            result.append([source[index]])
            continue
        else:
            inter_result = source[index]
            cut_off = ""
            inner_cut_off = ""
            # Get and append the first element of list
            while font.getsize(inter_result)[0] > max_length:
                # Put the last word into cut_off
                cut_off = inter_result.split()[-1] + ' ' + cut_off
                # Delete the last word from inter_result
                inter_result = inter_result.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
            else:
                result.append([inter_result])

            # Cut and append the rest
            while cut_off != "":
                if font.getsize(cut_off)[0] <= max_length:
                    result[index].append(cut_off)
                    # We do it to continue cut the remaining text off
                    cut_off = inner_cut_off
                    inner_cut_off = ""
                # Presumably further cause of error
                else:
                    inner_cut_off = cut_off.split()[-1] + ' ' + inner_cut_off
                    cut_off = cut_off.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]

    logging.info("Successfully split the list")
    return result
```

Она работает довольно хорошо до того момента, пока не придется зайти в **#Presumably further cause of error**, а точнее то что ниже этого комментария. В этот блок мы заходим только если исходный массив (а точнее элемент оттуда) длиннее максимально допустимой границы в 3 и больше раз. 
По итогу, если на вход подать массив где есть строки, которые больше в 3 раза допустимого максимума, то получится к примеру это:

```py
[['26 июля 1805 года в Италии произошло', 'извержение вулкана Везувий, пострадал', 'город Неаполь (214 лет) лет)'], ['26 июля 1867 года создано', 'генерал-губернаторство Туркестан (152', 'года) года)'], ['26 июля 1875 года основан Тульский', 'станколитейный завод (144 года) '], ['26 июля 1925 года впервые состоялся полет', 'первого советского серийного', 'пассажирского самолета «К-1» (94 года)', 'года) ']
```

То есть мы видим, что последнее слово дублируется. 
Или же, если например подать такой массив:

```py
['Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют потому, что тот обеспечивает более или менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а также реальное распределение букв и пробелов в абзацах, которое не получается при простой дубликации "Здесь ваш текст..']
```

То на выходе получится это:

```py
[['Давно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и', 'композиции читаемый текст мешает', 'сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют', 'потому, что тот обеспечивает более или', 'менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а', 'также реальное распределение букв и', 'пробелов в абзацах, которое не получается', 'при простой дубликации "Здесь ваш текст..', 'текст.. текст.. текст.. текст.. текст.. текст..', 'текст.. текст.. ']]
```

Я думаю что тут не так понятно. 

**Как это исправить?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально я подозревал, что проблема была в этой строке:

```py
inner_cut_off = cut_off.split()[-1] + ' ' + inner_cut_off
```

Но, после того как я несколько раз всю эту функцию построчно продебажил, до меня дошло, что в этой строке все хорошо, а не хорошо в переменной откуда все это отрезалось, то есть *cut_off*. 
В итоге, внимательно перечитав документацию функции *rsplit()*, решил доверится встроенному алгоритму отделения пробелов, переписав код так:

```py
cut_off = cut_off.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0]
```

Именно это и решило проблему!